# Fabricjs v2.4.1 loadFromJSON generated from v1.7.17 image scaling issues

Tags: fabricjs, fabricjs2

I've a JSON object that defines an image on the canvas like so:

[image]

The JSON was created from Fabricjs version 1.7.17 and I'm loading that JSON into a canvas made from Fabricjs versions 2.3.6 & 2.4.1 and this is what the image looks like:
[image]

The canvas sizes are the same and the options for the canvas are the same. The JSON loads just fine in the 1.7.17 version. All the other objects from the JSON data load fine, the image box is the right width/height and placement (left & top)...it's just the image isn't scaled to fit.

I've tried setting the scaleX/Y, resize filters to no avail - anyone tackle this issue already?

Comment: can you add a code snippet?

Comment: Fabric 2.0 changed the way that height/width attributes are handled for images in order to support cropping. You'll find an explanation and example code for dealing with this here: http://fabricjs.com/v2-breaking-changes#image

Comment: Thanks `melchair` I'll give that link a read/re-read as that's likely the culprit. And `Marius Turcu` I didn't supply a code snippet since it's just a method call on the fabric canvas object: for example it's just: `canvas.loadFromJSON(jsonData)`

Comment: @melchiar - Thank you greatly for that link, that was exactly what the issue was. If you'd like to put that comment into the form of an answer I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: @JoeManFoo, were you able to fix the issue? I am facing the same error and was wondering if you could help.

Comment: @Sanchit - Yes I was able to follow the instructions from the link in the accepted answer. Good luck and if you have any problems let me know and I can try to help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fabric 2.0 changed the way that height/width attributes are handled for images in order to support cropping. You'll find an explanation and example code for dealing with this here:

http://fabricjs.com/v2-breaking-changes#image